# Adding arrows to curve

Tags: arrows, arrow-curve

I tried using google and looking for old threads that cover the exact same question. I actually found a few suggestions that look great but unfortunately i lack the skills to apply them to my own tikz-picture and therefore i am looking for help.

this is the curve i created:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[label=below:$x_0$] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[label=below:$x_2$] (B) at (3,1){};
  \node[label=below:$x_1$] (C) at (1.25,0.65) {};
  \node[label=below:$\alpha$] (D) at (0.55,0.45) {};
  \node[label=below:$\beta$] (E) at (2,0.45) {};

  \draw[thick] plot [smooth, tension=0.75] coordinates {(0,0) 
  (0.55,0.45) (1.25,0.65) (2,0.45) (3,1)};

  \draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);
  \draw [fill=black] (B) circle (1pt);
  \draw [fill=black] (C) circle (1pt);  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i know it's not much i can bring up but i tried adding arrows by myself for hours and this is basically the only codeblock i was not being forced to delete after giving up.

the arrows are supposed to be on the curve right above $\alpha$ and $\beta$. can someone help me doing this?

I already tried a few solutions but it either didn't work or i did not know how to apply it properly.

i really appreciate any help!

Comment: I believe that you better do two things, say, bringing your snippet up as a fully compilable file, and adding a simple sketch which explains exactly how the desired arcs should look like.

Comment: you're right. i'll consider it in the future. thank you for the advise and your great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly got what you want, you can use the `decorations.markings` library of `tikz` package as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[thick,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{>}},
    mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{>}}}
] 
\node[label=below:$x_0$] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[label=below:$x_2$] (B) at (3,1){};
\node[label=below:$x_1$] (C) at (1.25,0.65) {};
\node[label=below:$\alpha$] (D) at (0.55,0.45) {};
\node[label=below:$\beta$] (E) at (2,0.45) {};

\draw[thick,postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth, tension=0.75] coordinates {(0,0) 
    (0.55,0.45) (1.25,0.65) (2,0.45) (3,1)};
\end{scope}

\draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);
\draw [fill=black] (B) circle (1pt);
\draw [fill=black] (C) circle (1pt);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which ends up with

[image]

If the directions of the arrowheads are not what you want, you can simply substitute any of the responsible commands `\arrow{>}` with `\arrow{<}`.

Comment: oh wow! this is exactly what i wanted! thank you so much @Roboticist. I am actually surprised how easily you've done it. The solutions i found were all way more difficult, that's why i didnt manage to get it done myself. thank you 1000x!